# Image transformation for Kinect game

Tags: image, image-processing, matrix, transform, kinect

I am working on a Kinect game where I am supposed "to dress" the player into a kind of garment.
As the player should always stand directly in front of the device, I am using a simple jpg file for this "dressing".

My problem starts when the user, while still standing in the frontal position, **bends the knees or leans right or left**. I want to apply an appropriate transform to this "dress" image so that it still will cover player's body more or less correctly.

From Kinect sensors I can get a current information about the following player's body parts positions:

[image]

Is there any library (C++, C#, Java) or a known algorithm that can make such transformation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complex task but possible.

I would split the 'dress' into arms, torso/upper body and lower. you could then use (from memory) AffineTransform in java though most languages have algorithms for matrix transforms against images.

The reason I suggest splitting the image is that when you do a transform you will be distorting the top part of the image and it will allow you to do some rotation (for when people lean) and wrap the arms as they move also.

EDIT:

I would also NOT transform each frame (cpu intensive) I would create a rainbow table of the possible angles and do a lookup for the image

Comment: Are you aware of any library doing such things, commercial or open source? Thanks.

Comment: I would be amazed if you can find a library to do precisely what you want - you will have to almost certainly roll your own as it is so specific BUT you do have all the tools in most major languages to do what you need - google image transforms in your language of choice